# Cannot remove group rights on Mac OS X folder

Tags: macos, mac, permissions

I have configured two user groups on Mac OS X Server (10.5.8): Administration and Personnel. I've been using chown and chmod to set the group rights recursively on folders. Now I notice that the Personnel group has "custom" rights on the main Administration folder.

I want to delete the "Personnel" group by right mouse clicking the folder > get info and press "-" after selecting the group, but this is not working. I guess this is caused because the subfolders and files in subfolders als have the "Personnel" group rights and I need to delete these first.

Is there a terminal command to recursively delete a group from the folder and file rights?

Thanks!

Comment: You find tons of articles describing how to set and change rights, but I never find anything about removing rights. Can someone help me out here?

I want to delete the Personnel rights completely from the shared folder. Thanks!

Comment: You can do that using chown, but since chown means change ownership, you can "delete/Deny access" the personnel group by assigning the folder to a different group (say Administration) group. If you don't want the Administration group to have ownership, then simply create a new group, or even assign it to "root" and then only root user have access. Try this command on a smaller subset of folders "sudo chown -R root /folder" (change /folder to what you want, -R is recursively down the subfolders and files) before testing it on the root folder of what you want to take ownership.

Comment: Thanks Darius. I want to deny access to the Personnel group. Is that something like "sudo chown -R :Personnel deny ."?

Comment: How do I deny all for this group? Personnel shouldn't be able to see the folder at all..

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
sudo chown -R root /folder
```

This will change the ownership of /folder to root.

And then

```
sudo chmod go-rwx -R /folder
```

This will then remove the read/write/execute access from "group" and "others" and leave only "owner" can do stuff with it (which after the above chown command, the owner is set to root)

After you done this, no one (except root) can have access to the /folder and all the files and sub-folder if you keep the -R.

If I'm not wrong (I can't say for sure as I haven't tested this), as long as you remove the permission on the top level directory (/folder), the other user / other group users can't traverse into the directory even if they have permission on the sub folder.

**Edit to add answer to the comment**

> Can this solution cause trouble if I want to give a new group of users
>   access to the folder?

It may. To ensure that "Group" still have access to the /folder, you should be using:

```
sudo chown -R root:rootgroup /folder    
sudo chmod o-rwx -R /folder
```

This will only remove "other" (that are not the user, and are not part of the group) access. Now anyone that are not root, or part of rootgroup will not have access to the folder. But this will preserve whatever "group" and "user" permission that they currently have on the folder.

Then in the future, if you need to add new groups (eg. itguys) to have access to the folder, you can simply change the ownership of the folder to the new group:

```
sudo chown -R :itguys /folder
```

This will make the folder owned by whoever the previous owner (in this example, it will still be root), and accessible by the "itguys" group members.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Darius! Can this solution cause trouble if I want to give a new group of users access to the folder?

Comment: I think we are making this more difficult than necessary. Please check http://www.contactpunt.be/permissions.png. That's what I see now. 1) Administratie is two times in this list. One with only read rights and one time with read and write rights. This should be only one time with read and write. 2) ctp needs to be removed from this list. How can I do this recursively? That's the only question I have.

Comment: Mac being mac you should be able to select, and press minus. I'm not sure why the Mac shows you that way. Have you considered using Disk Utility and do a Repair Permission?

Comment: I know I can select it and click minus to remove it, but there are about 2000 files in the folder. So I need to do it through the terminal I guess?

Comment: You don't really need to. If you remove the permission from the top level folder, the user can't access the content of the folder anyway. So even if they have permission for the files inside the folder, they can't even open the folder.

Comment: That's right, but on the top level I'm not able to use the minus on "ctp". And for "administratie" I have to change the read rights to read & write for all files. This should be easy with a command, no?

Comment: I just realized.. rather than deleting "ctp", why not just change it to No Access. And then click on the cog-wheel next to it, and choose "Apply to Enclosed Items" which should means everything under that folder. And you can do the same for your Administratie - change to read&write and click on Apply to enclosed items.

Comment: I thought of that too. That would be a solution, but I can't do it manually because I don't have the option. It just says read, read & write.